# Rails array sort_by works in Rails Console but not controller, throws "comparison of Float with Float failed"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters

In my controller, I have the following:

```
@destinations = Location.all.where("current_forecast like ?", params[:weather])

@destinations.sort_by{ |d|
  d.distance_to([params[:latitude], params[:longitude]])
}.first
```

This throws a "comparison of Float with Float failed" error.  However, if I enter the following in the console:

```
@destinations = Location.all.where("current_forecast like ?", params[:weather])

@destinations.sort_by{ |d|
  d.distance_to([34, -112])
}
```

I do not get this error.  Why?

Answer (score 0):

The values in the `params` hash are strings, and needed to be converted to floats.  The answer was simply changing the arguments for `distance_to` to floats:

```
  d.distance_to([params[:latitude].to_f, params[:longitude].to_f])
```